# Why isn't my StackExchange Inbox notification disappearing after I view the responses it is referring to?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

The notification below doesn't go away unless I click on it, even if I've already seen the responses it's referring to.

[image]

This is especially annoying when I know I've looked at the responses already, since then the notification just becomes something I have to click so that it will go away, but I don't get any new information from.

Is there some sort of option to modify this behavior?

---

I naturally click on the envelope to go to the summary page. This makes the lighted-up envelope dim, and I see the responses, so now I have no reason to click on the inbox, or if I click on the inbox, I can navigate directly to the responses, so I have no reason to click on the envelope, so each should be able to easily disable the other.

Comment: Do you mean you want the inbox to "know" that you looked at a comment / answer or question after the notification is inserted in the timeline?

Comment: @waffles - Yes. Exactly. ---- If that's not feasible, I'd just like to be able to turn off either the inbox or the envelope.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't gotten more attention, the behavior is just so wrong.

Comment: The envelope is just a distant memory. The global inbox is now the only game in town. Hence, this is too localized.

Comment: @PopularDemand Have a [meta-tag:status-completed] added too?

Comment: @Servy It's not exactly completed, just... some mixture of "no longer applicable" and "obsolete." It should really just be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible -- we're not even going to attempt to track every single item you've "viewed" across the entire network of all websites we run.

If you like, you can install a greasemonkey script to disable these areas, if you feel so strongly about it.

Comment: Of course it's possible. If you don't think it's possible, then do away with one of the redundant indicators so there's only ONE thing nagging people. The way it is now is a UX failure.