# Remove the Stack Exchange notification after replying to the comment

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

I saw that the inbox red notification does not disappear even after I have viewed the related question.

I saw on other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65785/%E2%80%A6) that people remarked that it is problematic to track every user page view across the Stack Exchange network.

**BUT**
Isn't it possible at least to do that after I have replied to the inbox comment? I can assume that the system "knows" that a reply has been posted, as it will send a notification to the involved users. So all it needs to do is to notify my inbox that the notification is not relevant any more.